# Requisição POST no Jetty Client 9.X

Tags: java, http-post, webclient, jetty

Estou utilizando o `Jetty Client` para fazer requisição à uma `API Web`, até pouco tempo estava tudo ok, mas senti a necessidade de enviar dados via POST.

**Problema**
Na [documentação](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.7.v20150116/http-client-api.html) do Jetty diz que os dados de requisição POST devem ser passado pelo método `param("chave", "valor")`, no entanto os dados estão sendo passado via query-string

```
Request r = client.POST(url).param("access_token", accessToken);
```

A requisição está sendo nesse formato:
*api.web.com/?access_token=1727020009.2da29da.ed9bdd6cc095430e8f1640bbeeas*

Verifiquei também a mensagem pelo wireshark
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já se deparou com esse problema?

Comment: Como você sabe que ele está formatando esse valor?

Comment: utilizei o System.out.print

Comment: Mas você chegou a executar o request e verificar na rede se está sendo enviado como query string ou não? Pois isso pode ser formatação na hora de mostrar

Comment: Acabei de fazer o teste com o wireshark, e editei a pergunta.

Comment: Da um system out na sua variavel "url" e mostra como ela tá

Comment: "http://api.instagram.com/"

Comment: Na sua imagem foi adicionado "/v1/users/self/feed", pode ser o redirecionamento que é feito automatico pelo jetty, o próprio Instagram te redireciona e joga pra querystring. Experimenta em outro site.

Comment: não não, foi que eu tentei omitir a url no inicio da pergunta...., mas a url está correta

Comment: Como eu disse, já experimentou em outro site pra ver se persisti?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, a documentação do **Jetty** até hoje está incorreta, segui o mesmo logica que o **Jersey** implementa, os dados via `POST`, devem está encapsulado em um `formulário`.

No Jetty a passagem de dados Post é da seguinte forma:

```
Request r = client.newRequest("http://localhost")
.method(HttpMethod.POST)
.path("/post.php?as=a")
.param("access_token", accessToken);
Fields fields = new Fields();
fields.add("post1", "valorpost1");
FormContentProvider content = new FormContentProvider(fields);
r.content(content);
r.send()
```

Que tem comoo retorno:

```
[POST] => Array
    (
        [asd] => asdasd
    )

[GET] => Array
    (
        [access_token] => asdasdasdsd
    )
```

Isso foi percebido quando entrei na `api doc` e verifiquei que o método `param` em `Request` não é para enivar dados `POST` e sim `GET` como é dito em outras documentações

[image: API DOC]

Abaixo temos a documentação Jetty informando que o post deveria ser passado via `param`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]